# Can I export the 3D coordinates of part of an object created in Geometry Nodes (without applying the modifier)?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes, linked-data, data-blocks, csv

Can I export the 3D coordinates of a part of an object made by the Geometry Nodes to a .csv file (without applying the GN)?

For example, I created this road (and its accessories) in  Geometry Nodes, the whole input is just a curve. I used the *Curve to Mesh* node to extrude lines along with the road-profile-curve to form the road surface, the same way I used lane line meshes.

I need to get the 3D coordinates of the lane lines and export them (as a Ground Truth for AI training project).

How can I acquire that data? I'm using Blender 3.3, on MacOS.

[image]

Comment: The ' 3D coordinates of a part of an object' means the coordinates of the lane line, a list of its points 3d coordinates. for example [(x1,y1,z1),(x2,y2,z2),...(xn,yn,zn)], N is the total number of the point along the lane line.

Comment: In what final form do you want these data? A CSV file, or suchlike? (Maybe this post should have a 'Python' tag)

Comment: .csv would be great because I'm familiar with this format, other formats are also acceptable as long as I can transfer that data to .csv. (great idea I'm now adding the Python tag)

Comment: Hi, miamo.. I'm going to edit your Q to make it more specific, then. If you don't like the edit, chuck it out :)

Comment: Thanks a lot !@RobinBetts